# setInterval not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have tried to make a real time chat, but i have a problem: setInterval (for checking for new messages) does not work :/... 
This is my jQuery code

```
    $(function(){

        setInterval(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "./ajax/checknew.php",
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#chMsgCont").append(data);
                }
            });
        },1000);

        $('#chMsgCont').load('./ajax/msg.php', function() {
            var div = $('#chMsgCont');
            var o = div.offset().top;  
            div.scrollTop( o + 12302012 );
        });
});
```

My msg.php

```
<?php
include("../system/config.site.php");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat_msg ORDER BY timestamp ASC");
while($p = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $auth = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat_users WHERE id = '".$p['auth_id']."'"));
    $update = mysql_query("UPDATE chat_msg SET new = 'no' WHERE id = '".$p['id']."'");
?>
<div class="chatMsg">
<p id="chatPMsg">
<span class="chatTime"><?php echo date("H:i", $p['timestamp']); ?></span>
<b><?php echo $auth['name']." ".$auth['surname']; ?></b><br />
<?php echo stripslashes($p['msg']); ?>
</p>
<p id="chatImg">
<img src="./images/thumb<?php echo $p['auth_id']; ?>.png" />
</p>
<div style="clear:both;"><!– –> </div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

My checknew.php

```
<?php
include("../system/config.site.php");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat_msg WHERE new = 'yes' ORDER BY timestamp ASC");
if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
while($p = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $auth = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat_users WHERE id = '".$p['auth_id']."'"));
?>
<div class="chatMsg">
<p id="chatPMsg">
<span class="chatTime"><?php echo date("H:i", $p['timestamp']); ?></span>
<b><?php echo $auth['name']." ".$auth['surname']; ?></b><br />
<?php echo stripslashes($p['msg']); ?>
</p>
<p id="chatImg">
<img src="./images/thumb<?php echo $p['auth_id']; ?>.png" />
</p>
<div style="clear:both;"><!– –> </div>
</div>
<?php
}
} else {
    echo "";
}
?>
```

setInterval refuses to append the results of the query :/, how is it possible?

Comment: where is `#chMsgCont`, can't find it in the HTML

Comment: Are you seeing any javascript errors?

Comment: Have you debugged it?  What are you getting back in data?

Comment: I don't see any javascript error :/

Comment: Here's a demo: [link](http://facebooktesttest.altervista.org/) login with these parameters: email: stackoverflow@test.com    password: stackoverflow

Comment: Just from a simple test, it appears to work but is flaky. My guess is it has something to do with post msg and not get msg.

Comment: @BradChristie, I figured out that it works only for ONE person connected to the chat, in facts, setInterval works for me, but not for User2, and User 3

Comment: @Denn: Probably because you need a more sophisticated way of marking the item read (would be my guess). First user to get the message is marking is as read leaving everyone else with no "new messages" to poll. Need to break the `new` column out in to its own table and flag per-user.

Answer (score -1):

May it must call window.setInterval() ?